# PyQt5 on macOS no space after comma and period in text displayed in a widget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, macos-big-sur

I have a weird issue that seems to happen on macOS (I have Big Sur 11.6.4), but not on Windows 10. Basically, in the text displayed in a QWidget with PyQt5 the spaces after commas and periods are not displayed (or very very small?).

Does anyone know if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong? Here is a minimal example

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget, QApplication

app = QApplication([])

label = QLabel()

text = 'This is a list: first, second, third, fourth, fifth. This is a sentence! And this is what?'

label.setText(text)

label.show()

app.exec_()
```

When I run this code on macOS I get the following window. As you can see there is no space after commas and periods, while the spaces are visible after exclamation marks and colons.

I made the text selectable, and if I copy and paste the text then the space is there, it's just a visualization issue.

[image: QLabel macOS]

I know that the bug was reported for Qt v5.15.1 and fixed for Qt v5.15.3 (see [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-88495)), but I have PyQt v5.15.6 so maybe I am doing something wrong?

### Update January 2024

I tested this on macOS Sonoma 14.1.2 in a `conda` environment where I installed `pyqt` with `conda install -c conda-forge pyqt` and it seems to be fixed. `QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR` is `5.15.8` while `pyqt` version is `5.15.9`.

[image: QLabel macOS update 2024]

Comment: PyQt versions do not match the actual Qt version. To check the actual version, print `QT_VERSION_STR` from the QtCore module.

Comment: Oh, thanks I didn't know that! So I have `5.15.2` which still has this bug. Thank you very much, I will wait for the release of `5.15.3` in PyQt.

Comment: Is this now fixed? I have `QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR` of `5.15.11` (for `pytqt5` module version `5.15.10`) and am getting the same behavior.

Comment: I just tested on macOS Sonoma 14.1.2 in a conda environment where I installed `pyqt` with `conda install -c conda-forge pyqt` and it works. `QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR` is `5.15.8` while `pyqt` version is `5.15.9`. Maybe is also related to the version of macOS?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by musicamante in the comments, PyQt versions do not match the Qt version. After checking the Qt version I have (with `print(QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)` I found that I have `5.15.2` which still has this visualization bug.

It is fixed in Qt `5.15.3` so I will wait for the release of that version in PyQt.

Comment: I got the newest version of PyQt5, but it hasn't updated in my code, so when I print out the Qt version, it still says version 5.15.2. Does anyone know how to get it to use the newest version?

Comment: The latest Pyqt5 is 5.15.7 which is still Qt 5.15.2, so this is not fixed on PyQt5 yet.